# Typography of Letters in Circuit Symbols

Tags: schematics, symbol

How should the letters in circuit symbols look like / be typeset, especially the symbols for voltmeter, ampmeter, generator and motor? Should the V, A, G and M be typeset in the surrounding font (possibly with serifs), in the surrounding sans-serif font or in a fixed (probably stylized and sans-serif) font regardless of surrounding fonts in the text?

Comment: I can't remember ever seeing a voltmeter, ammeter etc. symbol ever using a serif.

Comment: Often enough, it's not a font at all but hand-drawn lines. You can see it at the caps of traces.

Comment: Typography doesn't matter. The symbols are simply capital letters in whatever typeface you happen to be using. Their meaning is determined from context.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. Generally, use whatever is clearest, least ambiguous.

However, there's different *standards* that might apply. For example, if you publish a circuit, it'd be generally good style to follow good ol' DIN standard formats – which include a specification for things like page frame, numbering/naming of schematics and a DIN standard font. That font isn't exactly great to read (IMHO), being optimized for old pen plotters; however, there will never be an ambiguity between let's say a V and a U, an l and an I and a 1, or an O and a 0...

If you're contracting for some larger company, especially in defense, different standards might apply to you. Make yourself familiar with the demands of your audience! Remember: asking early is always better than being sorry after.

Comment: Thanks. So it is DIN standard font. BTW: I'm a teacher, so I'm possibly the only person in my institution caring about it and my "contractors" (a.k.a. students) care even less.